# Laravel how to pass data from controller to modal dialogue using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have items and for every item there are related items, so when I open the homepage it shows all item, when I want to click on any item, ajax will pass this item id to controller to get the related items for this item, the problem is I want to show the related item in a modal dialogue, the modal dialogue now show all related items to all items not to the current item.
I think the problem is because the include of modal in the homepage which has the foreach!, hope you can help me in solving this issue

**route**

```
Route::get('/',['as'=>'showItems','uses'=>'HomeController@getItem']);
Route::get('Get_relateditem',['as'=>'Get_relateditem','uses'=>'HomeController@getItem']);
```

**ajax**

```
$(function(){
$('.Item_root').on("click", function () {
var item_id = $(this).data('id');
 $.ajax({
    type:'get',
     url: '/',
       data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
       'item_id':item_id,                    
      },
    success:function(data){}
    }); 
   });
  });
```

**controller**

```
 public function getItem(Request $request)
 { 
 $currentitemid =$request->item_id;
  $ritems = Relateditem::orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('ritemf_id','LIKE','%'.$currentitemid.'%')->with('items')->get()->groupBy('ritemf_id');

 $items = Item::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->with('category')->get()->groupBy('category_id');

$categories = Category::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->get();

 return view('home')->with('items',$items)->with('categories',$categories)->with('ritems',$ritems);
}
}
```

**modal**

```
@foreach($ritems as $item_id => $realtedItems)

 @foreach($realtedItems as $ritem)

  <div class="SuggestedItem_container">
 <label color="red" class="Checker_root Checker_red Checker_left">
      <input type="checkbox" class="Checker_input" value="on">
      <div class="SuggestedItem_nameContainer">
        <div>
     <span class="SuggestedItem_name">{{$ritem->riteml_id}}</span>

     <span class="SuggestedItem_price styles_small styles_base styles_spacing-base">+$3.95</span></div></div>

    <div class="SuggestedItem_description styles_small styles_base styles_spacing-base">
    <span class="SuggestedItem_category styles_bold">Appetizers</span>

    <span> · Edamame soybean pods harvested right before the beans begin to harden are lightly boiled and seasoned with sea salt.</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  </div>
 @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify routes:

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@getItem');
Route::get('/get_related_items/{id}','HomeController@getRelatedItems');
```

modify `getItem` to get only the items and categories:

```
public function getItem(Request $request)
{
    $items = Item::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')
      ->with('category')->get()
      ->groupBy('category_id');
    $categories = Category::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->get();
    return view('home',['items' => $items,'categories' => $categories]);
}
```

get related items for a single item id:

```
public function getRelatedItems(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ritems = Relateditem::orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->where('ritemf_id',$id)
        ->with('items')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('ritemf_id');
    return response()->json($ritems);

}
```

now for the js part:

```
$(function(){
  $('.Item_root').on("click", function () {
    var item_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url: '/get_related_items/' + item_id,
      data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
      },
      success:function(data){
        if(data && data.length){
          var con_el = $('.SuggestedItem_container');
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
            var related_item_el = "<div class='related_item'><p>" + data[i].id + "</p></div>"
            con_el.append(related_item_el);
          }
        }else{
          console.log('no related items found');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

this will insert all the related items inside the `SuggestedItem_container`

i didn't write the view template cuz that part is easy, and note that i only included the related item id as example cuz i don't know what fields the item has.
i hope this helps you

Comment: many thnaks, Unfortunately I am a beginner and I applied all the steps but did not know how to put your variables from ajax into the modal, also from console i got error : http://localhost/get_related_items/5?_token=BYxY2z621X4BmBLB4ClBBseNW95QRxrKVdj8qvWR 404 (Not Found)

Comment: do `php artisan route:clear`, it will clear the routes cache, lemme know if fixed

Comment: and i suggest you watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ6PD_jBtU0

Comment: the same error:  http://localhost/get_related_items/8?_token=BYxY2z621X4BmBLB4ClBBseNW95QRxrKVdj8qvWR 404 (Not Found)

Comment: did you add the routes in first step as they are?

Comment: yes, you know what I think there is another solution, what if we used leftjoin between the two tables? but don't know how to still use it while Im using (with) in the controller

Comment: you need to get the items and their related items in separate requests for performance, and to understand what i did you need to know some js, that's why i sent you the link above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174096/discussion-between-ahktm-and-hussein).